# Laravel 5.7. Subtract model instances

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection, laravel-5.7

I have 2 collections of models.

For example

```
$full = collect([
    [
        'name' => 'name1',  //id was omitted intentionally
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'name2', //id was omitted intentionally
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'name3', //id was omitted intentionally
    ],
]);

$diff = collect([
    [
        'id'   => 6,
        'name' => 'name1',
    ],
]);
```

and I want to receive such a result after something like this

```
$full->diff($full);

$result = [
    [
        'name' => 'name2',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'name3',
    ],
];
```

How to achieve that *without* `filter()` or `reject()` with `contains()` in a neater way?

Comment: I'm confused, you want a collection to take itself on a ->diff() method call and return part of itself back? what logic do you want it to use to decide what to return?

Comment: Why would a diff return `name1`? Wouldn't you want `name2` and `name3`?

Comment: @mattQuest Probably I do not understand something in the 'diff' method, but I've written what I want to receive. Just subtract $diff from $full. How to achieve that? What function should I use?

Comment: I think I got it... did you intend to put the $diff var in $full->diff($diff) instead of $full->diff($full).   Also, did you intend to put 'name3' in the $diff collection?

Comment: @mattQuest the output was intentional.

Comment: @mattQuest OMG, soory. I saw a mistake. Updated.

Comment: I've tried both ways to call `diff()`. None worked out for me))

Comment: I'm using `reject()` now, but is there any shorted way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a neater approach than

```
$profiles->reject(function ($profile) use ($existingProfiles) {
    return $existingProfiles->pluck('name')->contains($profile->name);
})->values()
```

But thanks to everyone. I've upvoted your questions ;)

Comment: But this is not what you asked :) You wanted solution without using `reject` and `contains` :)

Comment: I should have written "that is neater"))) Sorry for not specifying that. Just, you know, we, devs, always aiming for perfection)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say why you don't want to use `filter` or `reject` with `contains` but there is another solution:

```
$result = $full->pluck('name')->diff($diff->pluck('name'))->map(function($name) {
        return [
            'name' => $name
        ];
    });

dd($result->toArray());
```

As result you will get:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "name2"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "name3"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Just cause I was searching for a one-line solution, cause this is quite a common task)

Comment: This should be made an answer because I couldn't fine any shorter solution

Answer (score 1):

The diff method should work as needed with a new collection containing just the name property:

```
$comparableDiff = $diff->pluck('name');
$result = $full->diff($comparableDiff);
```

Comment: But what if I need to perform the same logic for models based on one `name` key?) I've mentioned it, but couldn't show in a simple code example)

Comment: as long as your "$full" collection and "$diff" collection have the same properties (ie: collections of the same model) it should work

Comment: Hm..are you sure? Cause it's not working in my case.

Comment: And I receive all items.